# One SPF record per subdomain?

Tags: dns, spf

As you all may know, only one SPF record should be set up in the DNS records. My question however is if this also applies to other subdomains.

For example, I send emails through AWS and the given SPF record is`"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all" @ noreply`. But I also use Protonmail with the same domain and the SPF record given there is `"v=spf1 include:_spf.protonmail.ch mx ~all" @ root`.

Not only is the subdomain different, but the protonmail record has a 'mx' in it too.

How am I exactly supposed to put this in my DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite happily have separate SPF policies for subdomains - the SPF at `example.com` can be different from one at `mail.example.com`. The *contents* of those records can be independent too, and there is no reason why the `MX` for `mail.example.com` can't be the same as for `domain.com` - in fact it is assumed to be unless you specify otherwise.

That said, it's not clear that you're needing subdomains at all, but simply to combine SPFs covering different sources for the same domain, for example the 2 examples you give could be combined as:

```
v=spf1 mx include:_spf.protonmail.ch include:amazonses.com ~all
```

The local part of the address (to the left of the @, like `root@example.com` or `noreply@example.com`) does not figure in SPF checks, so it's irrelevant.

If that's not what you meant, please expand your question.

Comment: I didn't mean '@ root' as in an email address, but as the subdomain value. For example, AWS check the SPF records at noreply.example.com. Protonmail on the otherhand just checks example.com

Comment: OK. Each receiving sever should check the sub/domain that the message is from  - and nowhere else. It's entirely reasonable to have a `-all` policy for a domain, but permit sending for a subdomain, and checking things in the wrong place could cause quite a lot of breakage.